# Can a single process be executed in two or more processors in a multiprocessor system?

Tags: process, multi-core, threads, multi-processor

I have heard that one processor can work on only one process at a time. Is this true? If so, then how can a single process be executed in more than one processors at a time? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most operating systems will allow threads to run simultaneously on separate processors/cores. Since processes can have more than one thread, they can in theory run on more than one core. [Synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29#Thread_or_process_synchronization) may cause one or more threads to wait until others have reached a certain point, but barring that they will run at the same time.

Comment: How does sharing of address space work across cores?

Comment: All cores have access to the same address bus, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, what about the cache, registers? Are they not shared by threads of same process?

Comment: In a multi-threaded process, the threads share memory. If different threads are run by different cores, and each core has it's own cache & registers, then how is that memory shared?

Answer (score 1):

One virtual core can work on only one thread of execution at a time. In essence, this is the definition of a virtual core. However, one process can be executed in any number of physical or virtual cores at the same time if it contains multiple threads of execution.